# Input muestra el resultado sobre tres selects

Tags: php, sql, select

Buenos dias estoy haciendo la insercción de pedidos y necesito algo de ayuda. La idea es que segun dos selects tiene que salir el resultado en un input.

Por un lado tenemos el `producto` que está en la tabla `productos`

```
+----+----------+--------+
| id | producto | estado |
+----+----------+--------+
|    |          |        |
|    |          |        |
+----+----------+--------+
```

El select de productos

```
<select id="select2-2" value="" class="form-control" name="select2-2">
   <option value="0">Seleciona un producto</option>
   <?php
     $resultisa = $mysqli->query("SELECT * 
     FROM productos WHERE estado = 1");                                                   
     mysqli_set_charset("utf8");
     while($resia = $resultisa->fetch_array()) {
  ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $resia['id'] ?>"><?php echo $resia['producto'] ?> <?php echo $resia['alias'] ?></option>

  <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

Por otro lado tenemos el `tipo de contrato` que está en la tabla `tipos`

```
+----+----------+--------+
| id |   tipo   | estado |
+----+----------+--------+
|    |          |        |
|    |          |        |
+----+----------+--------+
```

El select de los tipos de contrato

```
<select id="select2-4" value="" class="form-control" name="select2-4">
   <option value="0">Tipo contrato</option>
   <?php
     $resultisa = $mysqli->query("SELECT * 
      FROM tipos WHERE estado = 1");
      mysqli_set_charset("utf8");
      while($resia = $resultisa->fetch_array()) {
   ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $resia['id'] ?>"><?php echo $resia['tipo'] ?></option>
   <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

Luego tenenemos la tabla, que según lo que elijan tiene que salir el inporte en el input `Tabla posibles`:

```
+----+----------+--------+---------+-------------+---------+
| id |idproducto|  tipo  | entrada | mensualidad |  final  |
+----+----------+--------+---------+-------------+---------+
|    |          |        |         |             |         |
|    |          |        |         |             |         |
+----+----------+--------+---------+-------------+---------+
```

Aquí el Select para la tabla posibles:

```
<select id="select2-4" value="" class="form-control" name="select2-4">
    <option value="0">Selecciona</option>
    <option value="1">Entrada</option>
    <option value="2">Mensualidad</option>
    <option value="3">Cuota Final</option>
</select>
```

Y aquí el input donde mostrar el resultado:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control inputmiocont corpiii" id="eTotal" name="eTotal">
```

La idea que si eligen:

Primer select el `id:1` que es `Láser de diodo`
Segundo Select: `id:2` que es `comprar`
Tercer Select: `Value="1"`que es Entrada

En el input tienen que salir: `13225` 
Lo que tiene que hacer es comparar por que aveces el campo estara vacio ya que no existe esa posibilidad

**-----------------POSIBILIDADES---------------------**

Tabla `productos`

```
+----+-----------+--------+
| id | producto  | estado |
+----+-----------+--------+
| 1  |LASER DIODO|   1    |    
| 2  | DUALWAVE  |   1    |
+----+-----------+--------+
```

Tabla `tipos`

```
+----+------------+--------+
| id |   tipo     | estado |
+----+------------+--------+
|  1 | ALQUILER   |    1   |
|  2 | COMPRAR    |    1   |
|  3 | EXPLOTACION|    1   |
|  4 | ALQ.COMPRA |    1   |
+----+------------+--------+
```

`Tabla posibles`: *La pongo de dos tipos de productos, pero hay más*

```
+----+----------+--------+---------+-------------+---------+
| id |idproducto|  tipo  | entrada | mensualidad |  final  |
+----+----------+--------+---------+-------------+---------+
|  1 |     2    |   1    |    0    |     455     |    0    |
|  2 |     2    |   2    |  13225  |      0      |    0    |
|  3 |     2    |   3    |    0    |      0      |    0    |
|  4 |     2    |   5    |   1900  |     385     |   500   |
|  5 |     1    |   1    |    0    |     435     |    0    |
|  6 |     1    |   2    |  12900  |      0      |    0    |
+----+----------+--------+---------+-------------+---------+
```

El tercer select digamos que es para el filtro ultimo, si es entrada, menusalidad o final.

Hagamos algún ejemplo;

Elegimos del primer select el producto DUALWAVE
Elegimos del segundo select ALQUILER
Y elegimos en el tercer select MENSUALIDAD

Resultado= 455. 
Si hubisemos elegido en el tercer select, entrada saldira=0

No se si así queda algo más claro, espero que si, gracias!

**EDICIONES**

`Valor del id del producto`

```
<script>                                                          
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#select2-2").click(function(){
  var valor= $("#select2-2").val();                                                     
    });
  });
</script>
```

`Valor tipo contrato`

```
 <script>                                                          
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#select2-4").click(function(){
   var valor= $("#select2-4").val();                                                     
     });
  });
 </script>
```

`Valor filtro`

```
 <script>                                                          
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#select2-3").click(function(){
   var valor= $("#select2-3").val();                                                     
     });
  });
 </script>
```

`Sacar variables`

```
 <script>
   var idProducto = $('#select2-2').val();
   var idTipo = $('#select2-4').val();
   var idFiltro = $('#select2-3').val();
 </script>
```

`Query`

```
<?php $resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT " . idFiltro . "FROM posibles WHERE idproducto = " . idProducto . " AND tipo = " .idTipo); ?>
```

`imprimimos query`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control inputmiocont corpiii" id="eTotal" name="eTotal" value="<?php echo $resultado;?>">
```

Comment: Hola Miguel. Entiendo que los selectores los generas sin problemas, ¿lo que quieres es obtener el valor para el imput a partir de las opciones de los dos primeros selectores? ¿qué papel juega el tercero? Podrías indicar un conjunto de opciones posibles, en lugar del código que usas para generarlas, de cara a hacer la pregunta más comprensible.

Comment: Hola @Orici he añadido en la pegunta un apartado que pone -----POSIBILIDADES---- ahí esta con resultados reales, gracias

Comment: El select de posibles se tendrá que actualizar según cambien las opciones de los dos select anteriores pero también el de tipos se debería actualizar ya que no todos los productos admiten todos los tipos, según la tabla de posibles ¿Es así?

Comment: Hola @JaviMollá sip así es.. Pero si no se actualiza con las opciones posibes tampoco pasa nada, saldria importe cero.

Comment: Para poder gestionar este tipo de relaciones tienes dos opciones: o bien tener un método en el servidor al que le puedas pedir los posibles según los valores de los dos primeros select, o bien al cargar la página cargar todos los posibles y luego filtrarlos por javascript. Una opción para cargarlos todos de golpe, es con un array bidimensional en el que la primera dimensión sea el idproducto y la segunda el tipo de modo que puedas hacer posibles[idproducto][tipo] para obtener el valor

Comment: La verdad @JaviMollá que preferiria hacerlo todo con javascript, me gusta más y estoy aprendiendolo, puedes guiarme un poco por favor! Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que querés es filtrar, a partir de los ID's seleccionados, los resultados de una tabla. Si es así, es importante tener en cuenta que un `select` no hace nada por sí mismo, es solamente una lista. Hay que dotarla de lógica para que realice las acciones que queremos.

Para empezar, cada `select` tiene un evento "onchange" que se puede capturar y, desde el cual se puede obtener el valor (un ID, en éste caso) del elemento seleccionado. Se puede hacer con jQuery o con Javascript accediendo al DOM.

Una vez obtenidos los ID's necesarios, tenés que hacer una consulta para cruzarlos con la tabla final y que ésta te devuelva el resultado.

En tu ejemplo:

- ID Producto: 2
- ID Tipo: 1
- ID Filtro: 2 (esto deberías definirlo en una tabla y usar ID's en la tabla `posibles`)

> Llegados a éste punto, está claro que el filtro no tiene la lógica que
>   estás pretendiendo. No sé si me explico bien, pero estás utilizando
>   los nombres de las columnas como opciones en un `select`, y a razón de
>   SQL la consulta sería bastante complicada.

Teniendo la estructura como la tenés montada, yo cambiaría los `values` de las opciones del último `select` para que fueran textos con los nombres de las columnas que querés, es decir:

```
<select id="select2-4" value="" class="form-control" name="select2-4">
    <option value="">Selecciona</option>
    <option value="entrada">Entrada</option>
    <option value="mensualidad">Mensualidad</option>
    <option value="final">Cuota Final</option>
</select>
```

Luego, siguiendo el ejemplo anterior, tendríamos:

- ID Producto: 2
- ID Tipo: 1
- ID Filtro: "mensualidad"

Y ya podríamos hacer una `query` para obtener el valor deseado:

```
SELECT $id_filtro
FROM posibles
WHERE idproducto = $id_producto AND tipo = $id_tipo
```

Y actualizar el valor del `input` con el resultado de esa query.

> **NOTA**: No considero esta la mejor opción ya que la estructura de datos no me parece correcta. Yo cambiaría las tablas para no tener que usar cadenas en donde deberían ir ID's. Pero, conforme lo tenés, ésta es una opción.

Comment: Gran ejemplo me has puesto, pero tengo una duda, como hago la query con datos que me vienen de JavaScript? gracias @Andrés Marotta

Comment: Depende un poco de cómo estés pasando los valores. Por ejemplo, ya que estás montando la query en PHP y éste te permite abrir y cerrar código en cualquier momento, podés concatenar las variables al vuelo:

`var idProducto = $('#select2-2').val(); // Revisar esto, puede que sea un poco distinto en caso de ser un select`
`var idTipo = $('#select2-4').val();`
`var idFiltro = $('#select2-4').val();`

`<?php $resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT " . idFiltro . "FROM posibles WHERE idproducto = " . idProducto . " AND tipo = " .idTipo);`
`?>`

Comment: el var idProducto = $('#select2-2').val(); es php??

Comment: Echále un ojo a los identificadores de tus selects, porque el de tipo y el de filtro tienen el mismo ID, y eso va a dar fallo en jQuery.

Comment: No, es jQuery. Es la manera de obtener los valores de un elemento del DOM en jQuery.

Comment: Que tendria que poner en el echo para imprimir el resultado?

Comment: No sé si entiendo lo que querés decir. ¿Simplemente querés mostrar el resultado de la query ejecutada? Eso con `echo $resultado` después de ejecutar la query, debería funcionar.

Comment: He añadido a mi pregunta las ediciones que he hecho al final, porque no me hace ningún efecto, haber si puedes comprobar @Andrés Marotta

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83258/discussion-between-miguel-and-andres-marotta).

Comment: Te escribi por el chat mejor @Andrés Marotta

Answer (score 0):

Lo pongo como una respuesta aparte, ya que la pregunta en sí misma cambió.

Para empezar, tenés varias cosas mal:

```
<script>                                                          
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#select2-2").click(function(){
  var valor= $("#select2-2").val();                                                     
    });
  });
</script>
```

Estos scripts no hacen nada, sólo guardan un valor en una variable que muere al terminar la función.

```
<?php $resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT " . idFiltro . "FROM posibles WHERE idproducto = " . idProducto . " AND tipo = " .1); ?>
```

Revisá esa query porque estás poniendo un '1' a fuego, y porque no tenés bien la concatenación en PHP.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control inputmiocont corpiii" id="eTotal" name="eTotal" value="<?php echo $resultado;?>">
```

Esto no funciona porque `$resultado` no tiene valor al iniciar la página y no lo actualizás correctamente. Después de hacer la ejecución de la query deberías actualizar el input a través de jQuery, si no querés recargar la página (que es la única manera en la que PHP podría actualizar HTML).

No sé muy bien cómo tenés montado todo esto, por lo que me es difícil explicarte los pasos a seguir, pero sería algo como esto:

```
<?php $resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT "... ?>

$('#eTotal').val(<?php $resultado ?>);
```